# Connecting AWS Lambda to Local DynamoDB using AWS SAM and AWS CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on setting up a local development environment where I'm attempting to establish a connection between an AWS Lambda function and a locally running DynamoDB instance using AWS SAM and the AWS CLI. When I execute the following command, it correctly displays the mock data in my local DynamoDB instance:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

outputs:

```
{
  "TableNames": [
    "Users"
  ]
}
```

My local DynamoDB instance is running smoothly, and I've confirmed that it's listening on port 8000 using commands such as `lsof -i tcp:8000` and `ps aux | grep dynamodb`.

However, I've run into an issue when trying to connect to the local database from my locally running AWS Lambda function. Here's the error message I'm encountering in the Lambda function:

```js
2024-01-19T12:07:56.525Z    48624b94-7f68-45b9-a9fc-4f6d163b82c1    ERROR   Error connecting to DynamoDB Local: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  '$metadata': { attempts: 3, totalRetryDelay: 69 }
}
```

I've also included a minimal code example that still reproduces the error:

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, ListTablesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const DB_CLIENT = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: "us-east-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
  secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
});

const foo = async () => {
  try {
    // The error is caused on this line, meaning the console.log is not being printed.
    const result = await DB_CLIENT.send(new ListTablesCommand());
    console.log("Tables:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to DynamoDB Local:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I've attempted various solutions such as restarting the local DynamoDB instance, changing ports, and using `127.0.0.1:8000` instead of `localhost:8000`, but nothing seems to work. Unfortunately, there isn't much documentation available to help identify the root cause of this issue.

I also experimented with wrapping the credentials in a credentials object as shown below, but it didn't resolve the problem:

```js
const DB_CLIENT = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: "us-east-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
    secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
  }
});
```

I'd appreciate any guidance or insights on what values are required to establish this connection successfully. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I've edited the tags, because "locally running DynamoDB" and "locally running Lambda" have nothing to do with AWS. You have a connectivity issue between whatever runs your DynamoDB mock and your lambda code. You don't specify what it is.